# DialogFlow find entities in training phrases but not in user query

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow identifies all defined entities correctly while adding them in Training-Phrases but does not identify all same entities when asked as a user query.

Does anyone know why?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is the link to image]

Comment: There is no image link ... Edit: OK, I fixed your link.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that ordering often matters in Dialogflow - in your training phrase the entities are in the order location, price, home entity, home entity; whereas in the user prompt the order is home entity, price, home entity, location. This can confuse it.

So while it's not ideal, a solution that should work is creating different training phrases with each possible permutation.